# Como checar um array de forma rápida?

Tags: php, json, array

Olá, no meu sistema eu recebo uma requisição em formato JSON e logo em seguida é decodificada.

Esse é o modelo obrigatório que a requisição deve possuir.

```
array (
 "client_id" => "",
 "credentials" => array("email" => "", "password" => ""),
 "security_questions" => array("1" => "", "2" => "", "3" => "");
  "security_answers" => array("1" => "", "2" => "", "3" => "");
)
```

Como posso verificar se a requisição recebida pelo meu sistema segue o modelo obrigatório e também verificar se existe algum valor vazio sem usar vários IF/IF ELSE? O objetivo seria deixar o código menor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas bibliotecas que já implementam o que deseja. Por exemplo, [`particle/validator`](https://github.com/particle-php/Validator).

Para instalar através do Composer:

```
$ composer require particle/validator
```

Assim, você pode definir seu validador:

```
use Particle\Validator\Validator;

$validate = new Validator;

$validate->required('client_id')->integer()->greaterThan(0);
$validate->required('credentials.email')->email();
$validate->required('credentials.password')->lengthBetween(4, 10);
...

$result = $validate->validate($data);

if (!$result->isValid()) {
    print_r($result->getMessages());
    exit;
}

...
```

Mais informações você pode ver na [documentação oficial](http://validator.particle-php.com/en/latest/).